# Should config related to a plugin be executed before or after loading the plugin?

Tags: neovim

Given a neovim setup with a plugin installed in `.local/share/nvim/site/pack/<x>/start/`. From what I understand from the (neo)vim runtimepath, that plugin will automatically be loaded (otherwise it should have been put in `pack/<x>/opt/`). So if I have config related to that plugin, should that be added to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim` or in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/after`?

In my specific case, I have the `nvim-lspconfig` plugin installed and the following config is present in my `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim`:

```
lua <<END
...
require('lspconfig').ccls.setup {
    ...
}
END
```

Doesn't this mean that neovim will load the nvim-lspconfig plugin while executing my `init.vim` config, even though nvim-lspconfig would have been loaded automatically by neovim anyway?

Would adding this config to `after/` make it possible to execute it conditionally based on whether the plugin was loaded or not (in case it isn't installed on a different pc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't this mean that neovim will load the nvim-lspconfig plugin while executing my init.vim config, even though nvim-lspconfig would have been loaded automatically by neovim anyway?

Basically, a plugin is a collection of scripts. So what does "loading a plugin" really mean? As simple as expanding `&runtimepath` and sourcing everything under `plugin/` subdirectory.

However, the Lua engine doesn't require `&runtimepath` expansion in order to find Lua modules under `lua/` (and in last versions even Vim isn't strict anymore, so it's now allowed to call plugins' functions from `autoload/` right from `vimrc` without delaying to `after/` or `VimEnter`).

So the real point if it's okay to call plugin's exported functions before its `plugin/` was sourced as part of startup or not. Also, another question if those functions are okay to call before full application init (i.e. VimEnter).

And so it may depend on particular plugin, but in many cases it's all right.

> Would adding this config to after/ make it possible to execute it conditionally based on whether the plugin was loaded or not (in case it isn't installed on a different pc)?

`after/` is not a "conditional directory". It's just (the last) node in `&runtimepath`. So one knows that `after/plugin/` is sourced after `plugin/` was sourced but nothing more. Thus if you need "a condition" you still have to add it yourself. But indeed `after/` could be a good place for this.

Although remember that some plugins may not expect changing its settings at this point. Or, maybe, they need quite "expensive" default init on startup, and so doing it for the second time is not recommended.

IOW, if in doubt always look into both `doc/` and `plugin/` subdirectory. If during the startup a plugin only creates commands/mappings etc. (and this is the case for many and many of them) then you're totally free to do anything you like (except, you can't invoke those commands from your vimrc, of course).

Answer (score 1):

> even though nvim-lspconfig would have been loaded automatically by neovim anyway?

This assumption is incorrect. You're probably thinking of vim's autoload functionality. But that is not available for lua files. i.e., lua files do not get sourced at nvim's startup. Think of how you'd have to source a vim script with `:h :runtime` command; that's what `:lua require` is doing. In fact, you can replace `:lua require(foo.bar)` with `:ru lua/foo/bar.lua`.